# Finding the image of an analytic function using Picard's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here's the question:

> Let $r>0$; let $f:\Delta^\ast(\infty, r):=\{z\in\mathbb C;\mid z\mid 
> > r^{-1}\}\rightarrow\mathbb C$ be the function given by
>   $f(z)=(1+\cos(\sqrt{z}))e^z$. Find $f(\Delta^\ast(\infty, r))$.

**My attempt**: By Picard's theorem, the set $M:=\mathbb{C}-f(\Delta^\ast(\infty, r))$ contains at most one point. Since $f$ satisfies $f(z)=\overline {f(\bar z)}$ and $f(\Delta^\ast(\infty, r))$ contains all positive reals, if there is a point in $M$, it has to be a negative real number. But I have no idea how to tell if $M$ even contains a point, and if it does, which negative real number it is.

This is as far as I could get. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!